# Como reproducir un sonido

Tags: java, javasound

Quisiera saber como puedo reproducir sonidos .wav en netbeans. Averigüe como hacerlo y lo realiza, esta relacionado al evento de un boton o al pulsar un enter en la busqueda en un jtextfied.

El problema como tal es que el sonido la primera vez se escucha bien , pero al hacerlo en segunda o tercera vez, se escucha como doble o triple, es decir, como si se abriera el archivo dos o tres veces y como con desface, espero explicarme.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class AudioAcceso {

    public Clip clip;
    public String ruta = "/audio/";

    public void sonido(String archivo) {
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(ruta + archivo + ".wav")));
            clip.start();
        } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en audio:\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde llamas al método sonido? Puede que falte parte relevante de código.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de un código que hice, no se porque te ocurra ese error que comentas, pero en el ejemplo no ocurre eso que mencionas, hay que recordar que si lo que quieres es detener el sonido anterior al para dar inicio de nuevo a un nuevo sonido debes detener el anterior, no se si me explico, si aprietas dos veces consecutivas el botón se reproducirá el sonido dos veces encimado uno del otro, ya por ultimo recordar que si mal no recuerdo el bitrate que soporta la librería de Java en archivos .WAV es de 16 bits a 44,100Hz si reproduces superior, marcará error.

El código le hace falta muchas mas validaciones y filtros, pero es funcional:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Audio extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lbNombre, lbElNombre, lbSeleccionar, lbReproducir;
    private JButton btnSeleccionar, btnReproducir;
    private JFileChooser fcArchivo;
    private File ruta;

    public Audio() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(180, 215);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);

        lbNombre = new JLabel("Nombre: ");
        lbNombre.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        lbElNombre = new JLabel("...");
        lbElNombre.setBounds(10, 35, 300, 25);
        lbSeleccionar = new JLabel("Seleccionar: ");
        lbSeleccionar.setBounds(10, 60, 100, 25);
        btnSeleccionar = new JButton("Seleccionar");
        btnSeleccionar.setBounds(10, 85, 120, 25);
        lbReproducir = new JLabel("Reproducir: ");
        lbReproducir.setBounds(10, 110, 80, 25);
        btnReproducir = new JButton("Play");
        btnReproducir.setBounds(10, 135, 120, 25);

        ruta = null;

        btnSeleccionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                fcArchivo = new JFileChooser();
                fcArchivo.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
                ruta = fcArchivo.getSelectedFile();
                if (ruta != null) {
                    lbElNombre.setText(ruta.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        btnReproducir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ruta != null) {
                    try {
                        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ruta));
                        clip.start();
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Audio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Audio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Audio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Audio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        add(lbNombre);
        add(lbElNombre);
        add(lbSeleccionar);
        add(btnSeleccionar);
        add(lbReproducir);
        add(btnReproducir);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Audio audio = new Audio();
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda deja un comentario.

Saludos

Comment: Como comentas, no ocurre lo que menciono al agregarlo a un evento de un botón, lo que pasa es que lo estoy ligando a un lector biometrico Digital persona. para que cuando capture la huella, la compare y esta sea correcta reproduzca el sonido. Ando desarrollando un reloj checador con biometria. y ahi es donde ya me provoca ese inconveniente pero como tal al llamar el codigo en un boton lo hace sin que se escuche doble.